# What's wrong with my VBscript code?

Tags: windows, datetime, logging, vbscript

I write the vbscript code to monitor system starting and ending time but it's not logging in same day 'That means not open and writing the same date file how to solve this

```
Dim objFS, objFile
Dim crdate,ckdate,fname
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

do
    crdate = Day(now) & "-" & Month(now) & "-" & Year(now)
    fname = crdate & ".txt"
    if (objFS.FileExists(fname)) Then
        do
            ckdate = Day(now) & "-" & Month(now) & "-" & Year(now)
            objFile.WriteLine(Time & "\n")
            wscript.sleep 300000
        loop until ckdate <> crdate
    else
        Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(fname)
    end if
loop
```

Comment: Windows already monitors startup and shutdown times by itself. Check the System eventlog for messages with source "eventlog" and event ID 60xx.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I believe the Kernel Power events provide more accurate depictions of startup/shutdown w/ 12/13 Event IDs.

Comment: You mean Kernel-General, not Kernel-Power.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in google that is closing the file with
objFile.Close

```
Dim objFS, objFile
Dim crdate,ckdate,fname
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

do
    crdate = Day(now) & "-" & Month(now) & "-" & Year(now)
    fname = crdate & ".txt"
    if (objFS.FileExists(fname)) Then
        Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(fname, 8, True)
        objFile.WriteLine("-------------------------------")
        do
            ckdate = Day(now) & "-" & Month(now) & "-" & Year(now)
            objFile.WriteLine(Time)
            wscript.sleep 300000
        loop until ckdate <> crdate
        objFile.Close
    else
        Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(fname)
        objFile.Close
    end if
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows does this natively... you don't have to reinvent the wheel. You can pull this locally or remotely and more ACCURATELY with the windows events.

```
PS C:\Users\steve> Get-WinEvent -Log System | where {($_.ID -eq "12" -or $_.ID -eq "13")} | format-table -property Message

Message
-------
The operating system started at system time ?2017?-?01?-?01T00:51:20.610798500Z.
The operating system is shutting down at system time ?2017?-?01?-?01T00:50:53.812034600Z.
```